# How to join synchronous and asynchronous world?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I'm beginning with NodeJs and I'm facing a problem I'm sure a lot of people may already have solved.

I have a basic NodeJs web server that serves files if a file is found, or 404:

```
var http = require('http'),
    url = require('url'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    fileSystem = require('fs'),
    path = require('path'),
    util = require('util'),
    EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var mimeTypes = {
    "html": "text/html",
    "jpeg": "image/jpeg",
    "jpg": "image/jpeg",
    "png": "image/png",
    "js": "text/javascript",
    "css": "text/css"};
var server;
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;

var personneSchema = new Schema({
    nom: String,
    prenom: String
});
var Personne = db.model('Personne', personneSchema);

var personneAdresseSchema = new Schema({
    idPersonne: String,
    idAdresse: String
});
var PersonneAdresse = db.model('PersonneAdresse', personneAdresseSchema);

var adresseSchema = new Schema({
    ligne1: String,
    ligne2: String,
    codePostal: String,
    ville: String
});
var Adresse = db.model('Adresse', adresseSchema);
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function () {
    server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
        if (request.url=='/persons') {
            console.log('> Persons request');
            /* IMPLEMENTATION PROBLEM HERE */
            var retour='[]';
            retour=retour.substr(0, retour.length-1)+']';
            response.writeHead(200, {
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, must-revalidate',
                'Expires': 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT',
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            });
            response.end(retour);
            console.log('> end of main function');
            return;
        }
        var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
        var filename = path.join(process.cwd(), uri);
        console.log("> " + filename);
        fs.exists(filename, function(exists) {
            if ((!exists) || (fs.lstatSync(filename).isDirectory())) {
                console.log(">> fichier inexistant : " + filename);
                response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                response.write('404 Not Found\n');
                response.end();
                // Stopper tout traitement :
                return;
            }
            var mimeType = mimeTypes[path.extname(filename).split(".")[1]];
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':mimeType});

            var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
            fileStream.pipe(response);
        });
    });
    // Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
    server.listen(8000);
    // Put a friendly message on the terminal
    console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");
});
```

The problem is: the Webserver needs to get a response *ready to be sent before the end* of the "main" function. But if you try to do a mongoose call, it's not synchronous. If you put the following code in the main function:

```
Personne.find({}).select('nom prenom').exec(function (err, p) {
    console.log('> Persons request finished');
});
```

The log shows something like:

```
> Persons request
> end of main function
> Persons request finished
```

So the main function that needs "response" to be filled can't have it filled with `Personne.find({})` because `Personne.find({})` finished **after**. What is the way to handle this? I cant find a very simple, self explaining example on the Web (nodejs + mongoose always gives me solutions with either nodejs alone, mongoose alone, or using full Web frameworks, whereas I just need a simple working example).

Comment: You're operating under a wrong assumption.  The server does not need to provide it's response before the main function is done.  You can provide the response as part of an async response that comes sometime later - in fact many nodejs servers do just that (pretty much everything that uses a database).

Comment: In answer to your original question, you cannot make a synchronous thing wait to finish until an async thing is done.  JS doesn't work that way.  You need to program in an async way if you have async operations.  That means using callbacks and finishing your work when the async callback is called and letting the original sync function finish.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, but may I ask you to give me a working sample of such thing, that handles async database call and returns it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any code that you want to be executed after the database call has finished has to be in the callback function for the database call. So you can't just put the database call in your main function -- you have to move all of the code from your main function that needs to be executed after the database call into the callback function instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but may I ask you to add a working sample of such thing, that handles async database call and returns it?

Comment: @OlivierPons - you keep asking to return async data.  That isn't how it works.  Read Mike's answer.  That's how you do it.  Any code that uses the async result goes INTO the async completion callback itself.  You don't return the result.

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry if I didn't explain myself: I would just like to see a (working + very basic) version of the marriage: mongoose / nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the server to start after your mongo query finishes, you can either use a callback:

```
db.once('open', function () {
     server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
        Personne.find({}).select('nom prenom').exec(function (err, persons) {
            // Log the result of the query
            console.log(persons) 
            // After the query is executed, you can use the results anywhere else inside your logic
            if (request.url=='/persons') {
                console.log('> Persons request');
                /* IMPLEMENTATION PROBLEM HERE */
                var retour='[]';
                retour=retour.substr(0, retour.length-1)+']';
                response.writeHead(200, {
                    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache, must-revalidate',
                    'Expires': 'Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT',
                    'Content-type': 'application/json'
                });
                response.end(retour);
                console.log('> end of main function');
                return;
            }
            var uri = url.parse(request.url).pathname;
            var filename = path.join(process.cwd(), uri);
            console.log("> " + filename);
            fs.exists(filename, function(exists) {
                if ((!exists) || (fs.lstatSync(filename).isDirectory())) {
                    console.log(">> fichier inexistant : " + filename);
                    response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
                    response.write('404 Not Found\n');
                    response.end();
                    // Stopper tout traitement :
                    return;
                }
                var mimeType = mimeTypes[path.extname(filename).split(".")[1]];
                response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type':mimeType});

                var fileStream = fs.createReadStream(filename);
                fileStream.pipe(response);
            });
        });

    });
    // Listen on port 8000, IP defaults to 127.0.0.1
    server.listen(8000);
    // Put a friendly message on the terminal
    console.log("Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8000/");

});
```

Comment: It seems that using your code, when there are new Persons added to the database *after the Webserver is started*, it won't be visible in the Web because the query is done before the Webserver is started... unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. A query is executed, then the server starts. If new persons are added after the server starts, if you re-run the same query, it would display the new persons.

Comment: Yes you're right but in your code, when do you re-run the same query? It seems like... never. It seems like you run it once at the beginning of the server (which is an endless loop, and in that endless loop it seems there's no way you can re-run your query)...

Comment: I see what you're saying, I was confused by your intended use. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: I've modified my answer, let me know if that's what you're looking for.